# Help with geometry angles question

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

I’ve tried chasing down different angles
This is the farthest I could get. I don’t know what else I could do to find the rest unless I assume ABC = 90
[image]

Help

Comment: Check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49362/a-tricky-geometry-problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A tricky geometry problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49362/a-tricky-geometry-problem) - this is the link in [Math Man's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605635/help-with-geometry-angles-question#comment9704225_4605635) above.